# Single AD Forest - dev and prod environemtns

Tags: dns, active-directory, domaincontroller, sssd

I have a single AD Forest (Azure AD Domain Services to be more specific) and I have two environments (dev and prod), which talk to it. Let's say the domain name is: example.com

Imagine I have a VM in each environment with hostname: foo.
Now I want to domain join both VMs and want to access them internally using something like: foo.dev.example.com or foo.prod.example.com.

- Is it achievable?
- Do I need to create OUs called dev and prod and join machines to those OUs?
- Is it actually a good approach?
- To join my linux machines I use sssd and "realm join" command.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it achievable?

Yes. Just name your VMs "foo.dev" and "foo.prod" and join them to the domain.

> Do I need to create OUs called dev and prod and join machines to those OUs?

No, but you can if you want. You can always move them to anther OU later if you change your mind.

> Is it actually a good approach?

Only you can answer that :) It's whatever works for you.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, for your answer.
Unfortunately whenever I set my ubuntu/centos hosts to something with dot, everything after the dot gets stripped. Also I've read here: https://serverfault.com/a/229349 that having dots in hostnames is not recommended anyway...